# Hive - add column with number of distinct values in groups

Tags: hadoop, hive

Suppose I have the following data.

```
number  group   
1       a       
1       a       
3       a       
4       a       
4       a       
5       c       
6       b       
6       b       
6       b       
7       b       
8       b       
9       b       
10      b       
14      b       
15      b
```

I would like to group the data by `group` and add a further column which say how many distinct values of `number` each group has.

My desired output would look as follows:

```
number  group   dist_number
1       a       3
1       a       3
3       a       3
4       a       3
4       a       3
5       c       1
6       b       9
6       b       9
6       b       9
7       b       9
8       b       9
9       b       9
10      b       9
14      b       9
15      b       9
```

What I have tried is:

```
> select *, count(distinct number) over(partition by group) from numbers;
11      11
```

As one sees, this aggregates globally and calculates the number of distinct values independently from the group.

One thing I could do is to use `group by` as follows:

```
hive> select *, count(distinct number) from numbers group by group;

a       3
b       7
c       1
```

And then join over `group`

But I thought maybe there is a more easy solution to this, e.g., using the `over(partition by group)` method?

Comment: I don't understand how you are arriving at your desired output.  Where is group `c` coming from?  How is `dist_number = 9` for `b`? (there are 7 distinct elements [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15]).  What is the column `value`?  I don't see that anywhere is the data.

Comment: Hello GoBrewers14, I just editted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to use windowing functions here.  I'm not exactly sure how you got `11    11` from the query your tried; I'm 99% sure if you try to `count(distinct _)` in Hive with an `over/partition` it will complain.  To get around this you can use `collect_set()` to get an array of the distinct elements in the partition and then you can use `size()` to count the elements.

**Query**:

```
select *
  , size(num_arr) dist_num
from (
  select *
    , collect_set(num) over (partition by grp) num_arr
  from db.tbl ) x
```

**Output**:

```
4   a   [4,3,1] 3
4   a   [4,3,1] 3
3   a   [4,3,1] 3
1   a   [4,3,1] 3
1   a   [4,3,1] 3
15  b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
14  b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
10  b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
9   b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
8   b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
7   b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
6   b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
6   b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
6   b   [15,14,10,9,8,7,6]  7
5   c   [5] 1
```

I included in the arrays in the output so you could see what was happening, obviously you can discard them in your query.  As as note, doing a self-join here is really a disaster with regards to performance (and it's more lines of code).

Comment: Looks great! Thanks GoBrewers. Does `collect_set()` always return **distinct** values from the corresponding group?

Comment: Yes, by definition (in mathematics anyway) a set is a distinct collection of things.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement,this may work:

```
select number,group1,COUNT(group1) OVER (PARTITION BY group1) as dist_num from table1;
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that self-joining a table to itself is better than using windowing functions?  Please explain.